# How to find the marginal PDF's of Bivariate Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution, marginal-distribution

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint PDF
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}x^{a-1}(y-x)^{b-1}e^{-y},\quad0<x<y,\quad\text{Bivariate Gamma Distribution}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive parameters. Find the margianl PDF's of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.*

**My Solution:** For the marginal PDF of $X$ I integrated the joint PDF from $y_{1}=0$ to $y_{2}=\infty$ and I got
$$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x,y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}x^{a-1}\left(y-x\right)^{b-1}e^{-y}dy=\frac{x^{a-1}}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(y-x\right)^{b-1}e^{-y}dy.$$
We substitute $u=y-x\Leftrightarrow y=u+x$ with $dy=du$
$$
\int_{-x}^{\infty}u^{b-1}e^{-u-x}du=e^{-x}\int_{-x}^{\infty}u^{b-1}e^{-u}du=e^{-x}\Gamma\left(b,-x\right)
$$
where $\Gamma\left(a,x\right)$ is the upper invomplete Gamma function. As a result the marginal PDF of $X$ is
$$
f_{X}\left(x\right)=\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}\Gamma\left(b,-x\right).$$
which must be clearly wrong as a result, since the incomplete Gamma function can't take a negative $x$ ($x>0\Leftrightarrow -x<0$) as an input.

For the marginal PDF of $Y$ I integrated the joint PDF from $x_{1}=0$ to $x_{2}=y$ and made it this far
$$
f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int_{0}^{y}f\left(x,y\right)dx=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}x^{a-1}\left(y-x\right)^{b-1}e^{-y}dx=\frac{e^{-y}}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)}\int_{0}^{y}x^{a-1}\left(y-x\right)^{b-1}dx
$$
(which isn't far enough) and I can't continue.

I'm stuck with this problem for days, and I can't seem to find a solution. What did I do wrong when computing the first integer, and how can I compute the second one?

Comment: The joint density formula you provided has $0< x < y$, so to get $f_X(x)$, your integration limits should be from $y=x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: And for your last integral, try substituting $x=yu\Leftrightarrow u = \frac{x}{y}$, so that $dx = y\, du$, and the limits become $u=0$ to $1$. Also, $y-x$ becomes $y-yu=y(1-u)$, so $$\int_0^y x^{a-1}(y-x)^{b-1}\, dx = y\int_0^1 (yu)^{a-1}(y(1-u))^{b-1}\, du.$$ You should be able to use the Beta Function to help now.

Comment: Oh, of course the lower limit would be $y_{1}=x$ i totally didn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try and i'll report. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, i tried what you suggested and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You should post an answer then.